# To align the dropdown below the button in Chips Autocomplete component

Tags: angular, angular-material

In **Chips Autocomplete** component, I have added the **button** above the **dropdown** as shown in below image.

[image]

I want to add this drop down below the button, something like this.
[image]

Applied padding for both dropdown and button,but not getting exact result.
Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-ksxr3d?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html) link.

Comment: have you get the solution??

Comment: Stil i have not got the solution.

Comment: do you want to open dropdown ob button click??

Comment: No i just want dropdown's scroll bar little below the button as i mentioned in the second image.

Comment: do you want to show selected chips below dropdown??

Comment: I am not talking about chips, You can see the scrollbar right side the list.I just wanted to reduce the starting point of the scroll bar.You can see the image i have mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-tvbwfc)

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="277px" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
    <mat-grid-tile [class.fullWidth]="breakpoint == 1" class="g1">


        <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
            <mat-chip-list #chipList>
                <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
                    {{fruit}}
                    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                </mat-chip>
                <input placeholder="New Players..." #fruitInput [formControl]="fruitCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                 [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
            </mat-chip-list>
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
                    {{fruit}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>

            <div style="width: 100% !important;margin-top: 5%;border-top: 2px solid red;">

            <button type="button" style="width: 100% !important;margin-top: 5%;" mat-stroked-button color="primary">
<mat-icon>add</mat-icon>CREATE NEW PLAYER</button>
        </div>
        </mat-form-field>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have an underline below the input field like `matInput`??

Comment: Updated Code and demo both. any help ping me back?

Comment: Sorry to say, my requirements are still left, **Requirements**: 1)Only on entering to the input field th button as to display. and 2)On clicking the button nothing should happen because i thought of giving separate link to that button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain CSS to do that. Use translate - it will allow to move element relative to its origin on x,y axis by fixed amount (eg of pixels).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Comment: Where i can add  translate property, for the  **1)button**  or  **2)dropdown** ??

Comment: I want to  move the drop down.

Comment: The answer is obvious isnt it? Move dropdown.

Comment: I have tried still no result.If possible can you please edit in the **stackblitz** link i mentioned in the question.